# Execute test cases manually or individually in the Boost.Test UTF

Tags: boost, boost-test

I'm using Boost.Test for the unit testing of my class in C++. And I already created my test case using BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE. But I want to manually execute my test cases in my code. Like for example I have two testcases, and each test case I want to execute manually. Do I need to create a test runner for this? If yes, how can I create a basic test runner to execute my test cases individually?

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fairly minimal harness already supplied with boost as follows:

```
// --- start main.cpp ---
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN    
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( testA )
{
    ...
}
// --- end ---
```

After you compile the file and link it with the **unit_test_framework** and **test_exec_monitor** boost libraries you can run the resulting executable, with the `--run_test` command line switch to select individual tests to run.

```
$ ./main.exe --run_test=testA
```